# How can insert Hyperlinks for image fields in Django template

Tags: django, image, django-templates

I am displaying the database field names and values in html table in django templae with this code

```
<table id="listTable" >
        <tr>
        {% for fieldname in object_fields %}<th>{{ fieldname }}</th>{% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for object in object_list %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' as rowcolors %}">
            {% for fieldvalue in object %}<td>{{ fieldvalue }}</td>{% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now the problem i have one field called image_name and i want that for that there should be hyperlink inserted with the text but how can do that so that other columns don't get affected.

I use this code for all the tables

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case is add a property to the class that wraps the value of the field in an anchor tag and add that property to your object_list instead of the default value of the field. Here's a quick and dirty example to get you going.

```
#models.py
class MyClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    @property
    def email_link(self):
        return u'<a href="mailto:%(email)s">%(email)s</a>' % {'email' : self.email}
```